How to set tmux pane value as a result of command substitution
I need to update tmux pane_current_path to a directory above the present working directory, e.g. if I am working on a directory called
/home/user/product-featurex/productname
/home/user/product-featurey/productname

I want to show product-featurex or product-featurey to be shown in the pane title, so that I can switch between the features I'm actively working on.
set-option -g automatic-rename on
set-option -g automatic-rename-format "#{?#{==:#{pane_current_command},bash},#{b:pane_current_path},#{pane_current_command}}"

The above format, either sets the foreground command name or the basename of the path, if no command is running. How do I modify it with either tmux format options with b: (basename) or d: dirname or any other way?
Ideally I want to run the tmux equivalent of the following
pwd
/home/user/product-featurex/productname
basename $(dirname $PWD)
product-featurex



Experimenting with various constructs, the following worked, although would appreciate, an even better way,
set-option -g automatic-rename-format "#{?#{==:#{pane_current_command},bash},#(basename \"$(dirname \"#{pane_current_path}\")\"),#{pane_current_command}}"

